# Select only partial result but get total number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pattern-matching, window-functions

I got stuck on SQL subquery selection. Right now, I have a table products:

```
 id | name  |     description      
----+-------+----------------------
  6 | 123   | this is a           +
    |       | girl.
  7 | 124   | this is a           +
    |       | girl.
  8 | 125   | this is a           +
    |       | girl.
  9 | 126   | this is a           +
    |       | girl.
 10 | 127   | this is a           +
    |       | girl.
 11 | 127   | this is a           +
    |       | girl. Isn't this?
 12 | 345   | this is a cute slair
 13 | ggg   | this is a           +
    |       | girl
 14 | shout | this is a monster
 15 | haha  | they are cute
 16 | 123   | this is cute
```

What I want to do is to find ( the ***total number of records*** and ***the first 5 records*** ) which contains `'1'` or `'this'` in either `name` or `description` columns.

What I can figure out is so ugly:

```
SELECT *, (select count(id)
           from (SELECT * from products
                 where description like any (array['%1%','%this%'])
                           or name like any (array['%1%','%this%'])
                ) as foo
          ) as total
from (SELECT * from products
      where description like any (array['%1%','%this%'])
                or name like any (array['%1%','%this%']))
     ) as fooo
limit 5;
```

Comment: Why not run 2 separate queries?

Comment: @Yuriy Thanks, can you give me a example?

Comment: simple run the first query that returns count only and without any WHERE conditions or LIMIT limitations; and second query that returns all columns but LIMIT them to 5 records and uses your WHERE conditions

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks for reply. I thought about that, but actually, there is more than 100000 records, I asked this question, and some one said I should not return them all for the reason to count them

Comment: Do you want the total number of *qualifying* records or just the total number of records in the table? I assume the former, which would mean @Yuiy's comment needs to *include* the `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, it's a valid solution, that does *not* return all records, just the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function `count()` as window function to compute the total count in the same query level:

```
SELECT id, name, description, count(*) OVER () AS total
FROM   products p
WHERE  description LIKE ANY ('{%1%,%this%}'::text[])
           OR name LIKE ANY ('{%1%,%this%}'::text[])
ORDER  BY id
LIMIT  5;
```

Quoting the [manual on window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

> In addition to these functions, any built-in or user-defined aggregate function can be used as a window function

This works, because `LIMIT` is applied *after* window functions.

I also use an alternative syntax for array literals. One is as good as the other. This one is shorter for longer arrays. And sometimes an explicit type cast is needed. I am assuming `text` here.

It is simpler and a bit faster than the version with a CTE in my test.

BTW, this `WHERE` clause with a regular expression is shorter - but slower:

```
WHERE  description ~ '(1|this)'
           OR name ~ '(1|this)'
```

#### Ugly, but fast

One more test: I found the primitive version (similar to what you had already) to be even ***faster***:

```
SELECT id, name, description
    , (SELECT count(*)
       FROM   products p
       WHERE  description LIKE ANY ('{%1%,%this%}'::text[])
                  OR name LIKE ANY ('{%1%,%this%}'::text[])
      ) AS total
FROM   products p
WHERE  description LIKE ANY ('{%1%,%this%}'::text[])
           OR name LIKE ANY ('{%1%,%this%}'::text[])
ORDER  BY id
LIMIT  5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using postgresql 9.0+, you can use [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)'s for this.
Eg.

```
WITH p AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM products
        WHERE description LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%1%','%this%']) OR name LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%1%','%this%'])
        )
SELECT  *,
        (select count(*) from p) as total
FROM p
ORDER BY id LIMIT 5;
```