# Get total row number while only selecting a single row

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, where-clause, row-number

Related/similar questions: [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select), [Select only partial result but get total number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734535/select-only-partial-result-but-get-total-number-of-rows)

I currently have this table:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+
| id | accountId          | competitionId | rating |
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+
|  1 | theidoftheaccount1 |            1  | 100    |
|  2 | theidoftheaccount2 |            3  | 90     |
|  3 | theidoftheaccount3 |            1  | 80     |
|  4 | theidoftheaccount4 |            1  | 50     |
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+
```

I want to get the row with `accountId='theidoftheaccount3'`, so I call the usual SQL statement `SELECT * FROM competitors WHERE competitionId='someotherid1' AND accountId='theidoftheaccount3 ' ORDER BY rating DESC` and all is good.

**The problem:**
Now I want to to know the row number of the row I got but only out of all the other rows that have `competitionId='someotherid1'`.
This row number would be the 'rank' of the competitor out of all the other competitors in the same competition.

So basically at the end of the day I would get back:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| id | accountId          | competitionId | rating | rowNumber |
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
|  3 | theidoftheaccount3 |            1  | 80     | 2         |
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What's your DBMS version 8- or 8+ ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL version `10.1.19-MariaDB`

Comment: You must enumerate records (using variables or self-join) first, and then apply filtering.

Comment: I would like this to be as scalable as possible, what would be the fastest/most efficient way? I expect this table to grow very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `row_number()` in a subquery:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             rank() over (partition by competitionid order by rating desc) as ranking
      from competitors c
      where competitionId = 'someotherid1'
     ) c
where accountId = 'theidoftheaccount3';
```

EDIT:

An alternative without window functions is:

```
select count(*) + 1 as ranking
from competitors c
where c.competitionId = 'someotherid1' and
      c.rating > (select c2.rating
                  from competitors c2
                  where c2.competitionid = c.competitionId and
                        c2.accountId = 'theidoftheaccount3' 
                 );
```

Comment: Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.

Comment: @Akina . . . which was close to three years ago.  When I answered, there was no indication of the MariaDB version.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! Unfortunately I won't have access to my computer for a little while, so it'll be a while before I can try and implement this and see if it works. I also just now realized how outdated my dev environment is and I managed to update it.

Comment: After I updated my XAMPP setup, both setups work, although I found in general the alternative solution you provided is faster. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your database does not support window functions, an alternative is to use a subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select count(*) + 1
        from mytable t1
        where t1.competitionId = t.competitionId and t1.rating > t.rating
    ) row_num
from mytable t
where t.accountId = 'theidoftheaccount3'
```

For performance, you want an index on columns `(competitionId, rating)` (and another on column `accountId`, but it is possibly already there since this looks like a `unique` column).

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! In my table only column `id` is unique. Unfortunately I won't have access to my computer for a little while, so it'll be a while before I can try and implement this and see if it works.